# proving that the set of all english words is countble.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, infinity

This is the question :
Prove that the set of all the words in the English language is countble (the set's cardinality is אo)
A word is defined as a finite sequence of letters in the English language.

I'm not really sure how to start this. I know that a finite union of countble sets is countble and i think this is the way to start.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: This is not the way to start. Look for countability of the set of finite strings. The chosen alphabet is irrelevant as long as it's countable.

Comment: A countable union of countable sets is also countable.

Comment: @AlexR: the chosen alphabet is irrelevant as long as it's _countable_.

Comment: @TonyK Thanks I noticed that after reading on my found dupe. Edited within the grace period ;)

Comment: The set of all English words is finite, because there is a longest word.

Comment: @MarkBennet Haha tell me wich one then I give you a newly created one wich is longer. (There are tons of pre- and suffixes to chose from).

Comment: @AlexR There is an official record. Of course you can make a longer one, but that may stretch the idea of an English word, but it is a game to play. However, if the universe is finite, then the number of possible words is ultimately finite, because there is a finite word length which exceeds the finite capacity of the universe to store information.

Comment: @MarkBennet Well that turns to a more philosophical / physical question. The mathematicians can deal with infinite amounts of information :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are $26$ letters in the English language.

Consider each letter as one of the digits on base $27$:

- $A=1$
- $B=2$
- $C=3$
- $\dots$
- $Z=26$

Then map each word to the corresponding integer on base $27$, for example:

$\text{BAGDAD}=217414_{27}=2\cdot27^5+1\cdot27^4+7\cdot27^3+4\cdot27^2+1\cdot27^1+4\cdot27^0$.

This mapping yields that the cardinality of your set is $\leq|\mathbb{N}|$, hence this set is countable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22281/discussion-between-alexr-and-barak-manos).

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much !

Comment: @MattG: You're welcome :)

Comment: Mistake, fixed it

Answer (score 2):

The set $S_n$ of the English words with length $n$ is finite (this is almost obvious). So it's also countable. Why is it finite? The set $A_n$ of all sequences with length $n$ made up of latin characters is finite as it contains $26^n$ elements. Only some of these sequences are meaningful/actual English words. So $S_n \subset A_n$. So $S_n$ is also finite.

The set $T$ for which you have to prove that it is countable is:

$T = S_1 \cup S_2 \cup S_3 \cup ...  $

Now you have this theorem:
"A countable union of countable sets is also countable"

Applying it you get that T is also countable.
Thus your statement has been proved.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to show a set is countable is to provide a way of counting it - ie a rule to determine the position of any member within the set.

In this case we can start with all 1-letter "words", from a to z - there are 26 of these. Then we can continue with the two-letter words aa, ab, ... az, ba, bb .... zy, zz. There are 26^2 of these. And so on.

Any finite-length word will be assigned a unique position in this sequence, therefore the sequence is countable.